# J'ai trouvé ! as an expression

Tags: vocabulaire

In *Robin des bois*, when Prince John alights on an idea (English: "I have it!"), he exclaims:

> J'ai trouvé !

Neither WordReference nor the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver) has an intransitive entry for *trouver*. How ordinary is this expression? What's its register? Can it be used with any subject in any tense?

[image: J'ai trouvé !]

Comment: I have heard my kids saying 'J'ai trouvé' but unfortunately I have not paid attention on the context.

Comment: About the film. Could it be just a literal translation of the English dialogue?

Comment: @Dimitris The translation is pretty fluid and often non-literal, so I don't think that's likely it. And you'd think that even if so, they'd write "Je l'ai trouvé !"

Comment: https://langue-francaise.tv5monde.com/decouvrir/dictionnaire/j/j%27ai%20trouve%21

Comment: https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/eureka-jai-trouve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***J'ai trouvé*** is common idiomatic French, it is how we translate the Greek *[Eurêka](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eur%C3%AAka)*.

I believe dictionaries do not list *trouver* as an intransitive verb because there is always a complement, i.e. there is always something being found. It turns out that it is only implicit in this sentence. This can be called an *objet latent*:

> De plus, comme c'est le cas pour l'emploi absolu, l'objet interne peut disparaître sans affecter la grammaticalité ni le sens du verbe : *Jean écrit (une lettre) / Elle nage (le crawl)*. Ainsi, « les verbes régissant ou pouvant régir un objet interne présentent
> un "objet latent" qui a la possibilité de se manifester ou non » (Pino Serrano, 2004, p.58), comme c 'est le cas pour les objets directs facultatifs.
>
> Véronique Fortin, [Justification d'une distinction sémantique et syntaxique entre les compléments de mesure et les compléments d'objet direct](https://archipel.uqam.ca/5870/1/M13181.pdf), 2013.

In the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver), this form is documented as "*Empl. abs.*" (*Employé absolument***¹**):

> − Empl. abs. Trouver à force de chercher. *Je vous réponds bien vite, sans solution pourtant. Je cherche et je creuse. Nous finirons par trouver* (Hugo, Corresp., 1866, p. 533). *Tout à coup: « J'ai trouvé! », s'écria-t-il à la façon d'Archimède* (Billy, Introïbo, 1939, p. 47).

<sub>**¹** Sens 3 [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/absolument): *Sans la présence du complément habituellement exigé ou du syntagme nominal complet.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Where would you look for such an expression if you didn't find it in the dictionary?

Comment: It **is** [in the dictionary](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/eur%C3%AAka) :-)

Comment: @jlliagre If one knew to look up "Eureka" in the first place... What I would hope for is an entry for the calque!

Comment: Viande-à-chien found it, it is not listed as *intransitif* but *absolu*.

Comment: By the way, I assume it can only be used for *je*. Can it only be used in present tense? Is it a fixed expression like "Aha!" ?

Comment: @Luke No, no and no :-) [*Cherchez et vous trouverez*](https://www.bible.com/fr/bible/63/MAT.7.7-11.BFC)

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a different meaning to me: vous trouverez ce que vous cherchez, rather than "you will realize something, hit upon something, light on something". As Prince John uses it here, it means "I've got an idea!" or, as Archimedes used it, "I've discovered the solution to my riddle!" The thing you find seems to be of a different category than "whatever you're looking for". I guess more concretely I would ask: Can I say, "Il a trouvé !" if I see someone else in the state where they'd say "J'ai trouvé !", or is it fixed in that way?