# Comment traduire le « come-to-Jesus moment » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation

Dans un titre d'[article](https://montrealgazette.com/opinion/columnists/marlene-jennings-justin-trudeaus-come-to-jesus-moment) on trouve « Justin Trudeau’s ‘come-to-Jesus moment’ » (Marlene Jennings, Montrealgazette). Merriam-Webster définit ça comme « a moment of sudden realization, comprehension, or recognition that often precipitates a major change » ; voir aussi indirectement l'[adjectif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come-to-Jesus) et le [verbe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_to_Jesus).

Dans l'article l'autrice parle de l'évolution de son opinion sur le mariage des couples de même sexe et du cas du premier ministre qui a déclaré penser soumettre un renvoi à la Cour suprême du Canada au sujet de l'emploi de la clause dérogatoire, tandis que dans les exemples fournis par M.-W. on trouve les contextes de l'impact de la maladie sur les patients et de la réflexion personnelle...

> (1) *Well, in the early 2000s, I had my come-to-Jesus moment.* (Jennings)
> (2) *Justin Trudeau’s ‘come-to-Jesus moment’ / That the prime minister is considering asking Supreme Court to rule on notwithstanding clause is welcome news.* (Jennings)
> (3) *Many patients emerge from illness having had a come-to-Jesus moment that reorients their thinking.* (MW)
> (4) *… I had … a come-to-Jesus moment with myself. I remember thinking, "What will you regret if you don't try?" So I went after my dream …* (MW)

Comment traduirait-on le nom composé « come-to-Jesus moment » et doit-on faire des choix différents selon les contextes de ces exemples et pourquoi ?

Comment: Somewhat telling that the article begins with a gloss of "come-to-Jesus moment" for even the Anglophones :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Also telling, Wiktionary doesn't have it per se. I suspect it's used by older folks, and can't imagine it would be used in BrE (but I don't know really).

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/51874/1893

Comment: @livresque « Justin Trudeau a eu son moment "j'ai trouvé !" » ?

Comment: Lévesque l'a trouvé, il est rené.  Chez Trudeau on ne sait jamais, peut-être pas encore ?

Comment: @livresque Anyways, your comment is just a pun to plug Lévesque's name here, but it's ambiguous and it won't work with the other examples imho.

Answer (score 5):

Pour garder la métaphore religieuse (même si on pourra difficilement faire aussi hyperbolique que l'expression anglaise) :

> Avoir une révélation

> Voir la lumière *(familier, sarcastique)*

Pour ce qui est du nom,

> révélation

ou

> prise de conscience

> moment de clairvoyance

peuvent aussi convenir selon le contexte.

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que le mot *épiphanie* colle parfaitement à la définition "a moment of sudden realization, comprehension, or recognition that often precipitates a major change"

D'après le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9piphanie) :

> Prise de conscience soudaine et éclairée de l’essence profonde d’une chose.

En plus on garde la connotation religieuse.

Comment: Le problème avec épiphanie, c'est que pour 99.9 % des gens, c'est juste une fête où on mange de la galette ou de la brioche pour tirer les rois...